# Fix Excel Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following Excel formula that I'm implementing in the "Set Cell Formula" action:

```
=VLOOKUP(X2;Sumarias!C:D;2;0)
```

however, I want to modify it to search in the worksheets: Sumarias_JDV and Sumarias_SC.

I made this modification but it didn't work:

```
=VLOOKUP(X2;INDIRECT('Sumaria_JDV'!C:D;'Sumaria_SC'!C:D);2;0)
```

Comment: `VSTACK` the two ranges

Comment: ^^^^ `=VLOOKUP(X2;VSTACK(FILTER(Sumarias!C:D;Sumarias!C:C<>""),FILTER(Sumaria_JDV!C:D;Sumaria_JDV!C:C<>"");FILTER(Sumaria_SC!C:D;Sumaria_SC!C:C<>""));2;0)`

Comment: Or, `=VLOOKUP(X2; LET(_x; WRAPROWS(TOCOL(Sumaria_JDV:Sumaria_SC!C:D;1);2); FILTER(_x; TAKE(_x;;1)<>"Header_1"));2;0)`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya one note on that formula, it requires that the sheets be one after the other and one uses the first and last in order, other wise there may be other sheets involved.  But I like it, I did not know that TOCOL allows the 3D sheet reference like that.

Comment: Oh understood sir, what you are trying to say, there is a point thanks. But yes i should have added that caveat.

Comment: Also, with WRAPROWS/TOCOL if cells in C or D contain blanks, this will cause a shift in the results. I like it, but it's risky.